# GetLowestOfferListingsForASINRequest How to exclude own listing?

Tags: amazon-mws

When using `GetLowestOfferListingsForASIN` it returns a list of available listings including my own listing on Amazon.

Is it possible to exclude my own listing from the result of the `GetLowestOfferListingsForASIN`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `GetLowestOfferListingsForASIN` you can set `ExcludeMe`. By default it is false. Here is the behavior and a link to the documentation:

- True – Your own offer listings are excluded from the offer
  listings that are returned.
- False – Your own offer listings are included in the offer
  listings that are returned.

[MWS Product API Doc](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/mwsportal/doc/en_US/products/MWSProductsApiReference._V401383218_.pdf)

Comment: Thanks Bruno! I also realized that new API parameter after I post the question.